# Error establishing connection to SQL Server

Tags: c#, database

I just started creating a local database in Visual Studio for the first time and I'm having a hard time making it work.

In modify connection I tested and it works and also got the connection string:

```
string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=D:\Bratulescu Mihai\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\NodeBDatabase.sdf";
        sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

        sqlConn.Open();
```

But when it tries Open() it cannot connect. I don't know much about this whole server thing, I just created the db and it's DataSet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `SQLCe`  since I see you are reffering to an `sdf` file you should add a reference of  `System.Data.SqlServerCe` and try:

```
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
....
    sqlConn = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString);

            sqlConn.Open();
```

Comment: what do I need to import for Ce?

Comment: System.Data.SqlServerCe can be found in the installed directory of SQL SERVER Compact, usually..C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Desktop

Comment: I added a table to the DB but it's not showing in Server Explorer, how can I see what is inside it?

Answer (score 0):

are you sure about the connection string?
You could take a look at this site: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-compact/